# How to split a Java String into an Array and print the resulting Array contents without the Delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, stringbuilder

I am generating a `StringBuilder` from an SQL query result set:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
String[] systems = null;

try {
    ps1 = c.prepareStatement(systemNames);
    ResultSet rs = ps1.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        sb.append(rs.getString("system_name") + ",");
        System.out.println(">-------------------->>> " + sb.toString());
    }
    systems = sb.toString().split(",");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    log.error(e.toString(), e);
} finally {
    if (ps1 != null) {
        try {
            ps1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    if (c != null) {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(">-------------------->>> " + systems.toString());
```

What I am confused about is the string object it prints after the `split`, the first print statement prints:

> >-------------------->>> ACTIVE_DIRECTORY,

While the second, after the delimeter split:

> >-------------------->>> [Ljava.lang.String;@387f6ec7

How do I print just `ACTIVE_DIECTORY` without the comma after the `split`?

Comment: Take out the `+ ","` when you call `sb.toString()`

Comment: `systems` is a array which is a Object

Comment: Are you concerned about printing the comma, or printing the memory address, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to check out the oracle documentation on the Arrays utility class method [Arrays.toString(Object[] o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])). This will 'pretty-print' the contents of your array, rather than the memory address.

Also, the last element will have a comma at the end every time, because you are appending it. To solve this you could do:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll(",", "");
```

or

```
myString[myString.length - 1] = myString[myString.length - 1].replaceAll(",", "");
```

Depending on whether you want to remove the commas before or after the `split(",");` Doing this on the last element will take the comma out of the String. I recommend after, because doing it before will make your split not work!

Alternately you could do a `replaceAll(",", " ");` and then `split(" ");` but then you might as well just append spaces instead of commas to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

It prints out the comma because you appended it.
Just print out your array (system var):

```
Arrays.toString(systems);
```

Comment: Well I am adding the comma because it could potentially be a large String array with multiple system-names, I just want the first system name in this instance

Answer (score 1):

try replacing:

```
System.out.println(">-------------------->>> " systems.toString());
```

with

```
System.out.println(">-------------------->>> " systems[0]);
```

since String[] systems is an array of an object, it prints the hash.

Comment: @WhyCry And why do you believe so?

Comment: Misread the question, and yes, the comma will still be there of course

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg Why do you think, that the comma will still be there? `System.out.println(">-------------------->>> " systems.toString())` is the last statement in OPs code. Either you get a `NullPointerException` if the `try` block failed, or you get the first elements of the `systems` array, without the delimiter.

Comment: The comma will be in the first println is what I mean. The last println is the one that's always executed and will print the hashcode unless converted from an array of strings to an actual string.